# Next tab shows content but tabs don't follow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I have 2 tables separated with two tabs.
Active and Inactive

Let's say I click a next button from the active tab. The content of the inactive tab shows but the active tab is still the Active tab. Am I missing something?

Lets say their corresponding IDs are #Active and #Inactive. This is the code of the next button:

```
<a href=#Inactive data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
    <button class="btn next">Next</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Provide more code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code i guess that you're using **[bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)** so you should add `click` event in  your JS code to detect the click on `next` button and send you to the second tab.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.next').click(function () {
    $('#myTabs a[href="#inactive"]').tab('show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>
  
  <!-- Nav tabs --><br>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id='myTabs' role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#acitve" aria-controls="acitve" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Active</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#inactive" aria-controls="inactive" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Inactive</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="acitve">
      table 1 
      </br> 
      <button class="btn next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="inactive">
      table 2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I thought that the jquery script isn't needed so that's why